# rot13 not translating correctly python

Tags: python

I'm trying to translate a string into rot13 so I've written the following code:

```
def str_rot_13(my_string):
    list_string = list(my_string)
    number_string = [ord(x) for x in list_string]
    new_number_string = [x + 13 for x in number_string]   
    new_list_string = [chr(x) for x in new_number_string]
    my_new_string = ''.join(new_list_string)
    return my_new_string
```

My issue is that if I get to far down in the alphabet it starts to return weird numbers and slashes. I tried creating a range in ord('a') to ord('z') but it still returned the numbers and slashes. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: i'll take a look at it

Answer (score 2):

by doing `(((x + 13-97)%26)+97)` X value will always be between 97 and 122 (`ord("a") = 97, ord("z") = 122`) then you're output will always be a string exclusively composed of letters.

```
def str_rot_13(my_string):
    list_string = list(my_string)
    number_string = [ord(x) for x in list_string]
    new_number_string = [(((x + 13-97)%26)+97) for x in number_string]   
    new_list_string = [chr(x) for x in new_number_string]
    my_new_string = ''.join(new_list_string)
    return my_new_string
```

> output:

```
>>> print str_rot_13("my string")
zlafgevat
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of rot13 is that there are 26 letters in the (English) alphabet. Thus applying rot13 gives you the original string.
`ord`, however gives you the [Ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) symbol (there are 128 of those).

How about using `string.ascii_lowercase`

```
import string    

def str_rot_13(my_string):
    alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    list_string = list(my_string)
    number_string = [alphabet.index(x) for x in list_string]
    new_number_string = [x + 13 for x in number_string]   
    new_list_string = [alphabet[x%26] for x in new_number_string]
    my_new_string = ''.join(new_list_string)
    return my_new_string
```

Or shorter

```
def rot13(s):
    alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    chars = map(lambda x: alphabet[(alphabet.index(x) + 13) %26], s)
    return ''.join(chars)
```

Comment: I gave an alternative implementation and shortened it... the +13%26 part is kind of inevitable.